# Clean install of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I just want to ask if how to install ubuntu in windows. I want to make it in clean install, i don't want to use dual bot or alongside boot. But I don;t know what to do, cause I'm new to this OS. Please provide me a step by step process of it. It would be great. thanks

Comment: Just boot from the installation CD and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a burned disk of Ubuntu, you would then simply insert the disk into a CD-DVD drive. And restart your computer. If you're using windows it should either ask you to press any key to boot from CD-DVD, or Ubuntu setup will load on it's own. From within the installer you have the option of deleting all the files and installing a clean copy of Ubuntu on your hard drive. The installation is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: OK, after the installation of Ubuntu, do i need to install drivers again?